# Counterexamples concerning the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

The central limit theorem states that, if $X$ is a random variable with finite variance $\sigma^2$ and expected value $\mu$, and if $(X_n)$ is a sequence of independent random variables identically distributed like $ X $, then

\begin{equation}
Z_n = {\frac{{\overline{X}}_n-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n}}}\ \rightsquigarrow N(0,1),
\end{equation}

where ${\overline{X}}_{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ and $\rightsquigarrow$ means convergence in distribution, which in this case is equivalent to the pointwise convergence of the cdf of $Z_n$ to the cdf of a $N(0,1)$.

Suppose moreover that $X_n$ is absolutely continuous for all $n$‘s. Then $Z_n$ is absolutely continuous for all $n$‘s. Are there examples of such sequences $(X_n)$, such that the pdf of $Z_n$ does **not** converge pointwise to the pdf of a $N(0,1)$, not even almost everywhere (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$)?

Comment: Such $\{X_n\}$ should violate the assumptions of the CLT.

Comment: @d.k.o. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If $\{X_n\}$ is required to be a sequence of i.i.d. r.v.s with finite second moment, then by the CLT the self-normalized sum converges weakly to $N(0,1)$.

Comment: @d.k.o. I agree, but weak convergence means pointwise convergence of the cdfs to the cdf of the limit at all points of continuity for the cdf of the limit, and doesn't say anything about convergence of the pdfs in general. I don't think this case is any different, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I see. I missed that you're asking about pdfs. Indeed, weak convergence does not always imply convergence of densities (though, the opposite is true).

Comment: But so, is the central limit theorem valid ? Or do the counter-example invalidate it ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, the central limit theorem is valid. The counterexamples I was looking for regard something stronger than what the CLT guarantees to be true.

Comment: @Fererico : ok, but here, https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01350 the authors claim that they have a counter example for the central limit theorem.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, no, they don’t. They just provide a counterexample that shows that the independence hypothesis in the theorem cannot be replaced with the weaker pairwise independence.

Comment: @Federico. Thank you. May you comment why wikipedia english say : "in many situations" (that I interpret as "not in all situations") : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, the CLT’s hypotheses are not satisfied by any sequence of independent random variables. In the version of the CLT that I mentioned (the classical one) it is required that the random variables are also identically distributed. There are other versions of the theorem that require the sequence to satisfy different conditions, but you can’t expect to take any sequence of independent random variables and have their normalized mean converge (weakly) to a $N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This counterexample is from the book *Limit Distributions for Sums of Independent Random Variables* by Gnedenko and Kolmogorov.

Let $X$ have density $\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if} |x|\geq \frac 1e \\
\frac{1}{2|x|\log^2(|x|)} &\text{if} |x|< \frac 1e
\end{cases}$

The authors argue that $f_n$ the density of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ verifies $\displaystyle f_n(x) > \frac{c_n}{|x \log^{n+1}(|x|)|}$  for some positive constant $c_n$ in a neighborhood of $0$. So the density of $Z_n$ (which is a normalized version of $f_n$) is infinite at $0$.

---

They prove the following theorem:

**Theorem**: Suppose $X$ has density $f$. If

- for some $m\geq 1$, $f_m$ (the density of $\sum_{i=1}^m X_i$) is in $L^r(\mathbb R)$ for some $r\in (1,2]$,
- $\int x^2 f(x) dx <\infty$ (i.e. $X$ has a second moment)

Then $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} \left|\sigma \sqrt n f_n(\sigma \sqrt n x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \right| \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{}0$

In Petrov's *Sums of Independent Random Variables*, the following theorem is stated:

**Theorem**: Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of i.i.d r.v with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$ and let $f_n$ denote the density of $Z_n$ (if it exists).

Then $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} \left| f_n(x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \right| \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{}0$ if and only if $f_n$ is bounded for some $n$.

In Shiryaev's *Probability 2*, the following Local Central Limit Theorem is stated:

**Theorem**: Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of i.i.d r.v with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. If for some $r\geq 1$, $\int |\phi_{X_1}(t)|^r dt <\infty$, then $Z_n$ has a density $f_n$ such that 
$\displaystyle \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} \left| f_n(x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \right| \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{}0$

---

Regarding almost sure convergence, you should have a look at Rao's [A Limit Theorem for Densities](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25048460).

Comment: @Federico I haven't been able to access it either, and unfortunately it seems Jstor is the only place where it's available... Petrov says a few words about Rao's paper, see page 213.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/25048460.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ae109e881cbc54da127444b2ad59697e8

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend

*A Few Counter Examples Useful in Teaching Central Limit Theorems.*, [www.jstor.org/stable/24590348](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24590348).

As well as chapter 17 of the great book *Counterexamples in Probability* by Jordan Stoyanov.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y=1/X$. Then
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nY_k-\mathsf E_\mathcal PY}{\pi f_X(0)}\overset{d}{\to}\operatorname{Cauchy(0,1)},
$$
where $\mathsf E_\mathcal PY$ denotes the cauchy principal value integral
$$
\mathsf E_\mathcal PY:=\mathcal P\int_{-\infty}^\infty 
y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy,
$$
and $\operatorname{Cauchy(0,1)}$ denotes the standard Cauchy distribution. For this reason, we say $Y$ lies within the domain of attraction of the Cauchy law as opposed to the normal (Gaussian) law which is used in the CLT.